# Create an IntentFilter in android that matches ALL intents

Tags: android

Is it possible to create an IntentFilter in android that matches ALL intents that are Broadcasted on the phone (perhaps by way of using a BroadcastReceiver)? I.E. the ones I see in ddms when I use the phone, under the ActivityManager tag? After digging through the documentation, and looking at the framework source, I am left to think it can't be done? That you must specify some sort of data, to paraphrase the docs, "some sort of data must be specified, or else you'll only get intents with no data". The app I am writing needs to know about every app that is started on the system. So far, the only way I have been able to do this is by polling ActivityManager. It seems the best way would be to have an event driven solution, using whatever underlying logic ActivityManager uses, but it's all greek to me inside of the ActivityManager.java framework source, and seems like a lot of the stuff underneath (if not ALL) is deliberately encapsulated from me.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 - Interested to see the outcome on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said it yourself, the documentation quite clearly specifies how intent filters function and that this is not possible to receive all broadcasts.

Neither this nor retrieving task information is something that is supported by the APIs made public in the Android SDK.

Comment: sad but true, although from peeking in the android source, it looks like some of this stuff has been made public in the newest GIT snapshots

Comment: Even if matching everything is not possible, this answer would be more helpful if it described how to construct a filter matching as many intents as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a costume receiver for each event type that will hold a reference to a parent broadcast receiver and call its onReceive method

```
class ChildBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private BroadcastReceiver parent;

    public ChildBroadcastReceiver(BroadcastReceiver parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        parent.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Then you can register to all the possible events by using reflection:

```
final BroadcastReceiver parent = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           android.util.Log.d("GlobalBroadcastReceiver", "Recieved: " +   intent.getAction() + " " + context.toString());
      }
};

Intent intent = new Intent();
for(Field field : intent.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
    if( Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) &&
        Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) &&
        Modifier.isFinal(modifiers) &&
        field.getType().equals(String.class)) {

            String filter = (String)field.get(intent);
            android.util.Log.d("GlobalBroadcastReceiver", "Registered: " + filter);
            application.registerReceiver(new ChildBroadcastReceiver(parent), new IntentFilter(filter));
        }
}
```