# Android : Broadcast not being received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am attempting to send a broadcast from an IntentService, I am having no luck.

**MainActivity**

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    Context context = this;
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("io.a.spike");

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("*******  received broadcast *******");
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

**IntentService**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("send broadcast");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    notificationIntent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction("io.a.spike");
    sendBroadcast(notificationIntent);
}
```

I am not getting to the **onReceive** method within my registerBroadcastReceiver method. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting the log of "send broadcast" which you have put inside onHandleIntent()??

Comment: Try context.sendBroadcast(notificationIntent); in place of sendBroadcast(notificationIntent);

Answer (score 0):

For getting your `onReceive()` called, you will have to add these -

- add your BroadcastReceiver to into **manifest**, in this way -
  `<receiver android:name="YourReceiver"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="YourAction" /> </intent-filter> </receiver>`
- call `registerReceiver()` in your activity.
  Also, don't forget to call `unegisterReceiver()` to avoid leaks.

Also, refer [Android BroadcastReceiver without intent filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901195/android-broadcastreceiver-without-intent-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager`

Create instance

> LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =
>   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

Register Receiver

> localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(new YourReceiver(),new
>   IntentFilter("YourAction"));

Send Broadcast

> localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);

UnRegister Receiver

> localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);