# Who receives this intent (no receivers registered)

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm currently digging through an app and trying to find out, who receives an intent.

I basically have something similar to the following (code is executed inside an activity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent("me.package.ACTION", "content://me.package/settings");
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT).send();
```

The problem now is, that the `"me.package.ACTION"` string is never used to register something as a receiver. It's only used to construct new Intents or in `Context.sendBroadcast()`.
Also there is no `receiver` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` which takes this intent.

So how can I find out, where the intent will get processed?

[AFAIK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403759/create-an-intentfilter-in-android-that-matches-all-intents) it's not possible to create a catch-all `BroadcastReceiver`/`IntentFilter`.

PS: The app requires a htc ROM and runs under Lollipop.

**Edit:** Is it possible that the intent is received in another apk?
If so, how can I determine, which apk receives the Intent?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PackageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(Intent, flags)` to determine that, like the following code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(YourAction); //Put any action string you have in mind
//Or any Intent intent = new Intent(...) you think fits

List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : activities) {
    ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
    if (activityInfo != null) {
        results.add(activityInfo.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't return any receivers for me. By looking a bit through my packages and examining a few I found that the Intent gets received by `com.htc.checkinprovider`. Could that be a reason why `queryBroadcastReceivers` does return an empty list or did I do anything else wrong?

Comment: @Uroc327 is the intent action in one of its receiver filters?

Comment: Not in the manifest. The filter is only registered using `Context.registerReceiver()`. (I just saw, that my comment is a little bit confusing.. By 'could that be a reason' I meant 'could the fact that this is a system app be a reason')